# Instance of connect-mongo module do nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connect-mongo

Hie. I've a problem. I use windows and my `app` is a `nodejs app`. I store sessions in `mongodb` and use *connect-mongo* module. And this is my problem:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://localhost/latte', db: 'latte' }, function(err) {
    console.log(arguments);

// ... some code use sessionStore variable ...

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen('80', 'latte.ru', function(){
    log.info('Express server listening on port 80');
});
```

});

When I create an instance of `MongoStore` callback doesn't fire and `console.log` doesn't fire too, but I have no errors in console.
When I run server without of `MongoStore` all is OK.
In windows console mongo works fine.

*Please help to resolve this problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this,

```
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 27017, db: 'test-app'}, function(err){
console.log(arguments)
});
```

Your MongoStore url doesn't appear to be in sync.